# Electric field outside a hollow cylindrical conducting shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

Imagine that a point charge $+Q$ is located at radius $R$ and height $z=0$ inside of an infinitely long conducting cylinder shell of inner radius $a>R$ and outer radius $b$.

From what we know of perfect conductors, we know that $Q_{induced}(r=a) = -Q$, $Q_{induced}(r=b) = +Q$, and the electric field inside the shell is  $E(a<r<b)=0$.

Is there a way to figure out the magnitude and direction of the electric field outside of the conducting shell as a function of position?

Comment: Yes. The [method of images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty This is not a *shell*. It has inner and outer radii. How do you apply the method of images?

Comment: It is a shell in the sense that the charges need to be distributed at opposite surfaces of the conductor. It's the wording of the problem I am trying to solve. But yes, I thought about using the method of images but have no idea how to distribute charges in order to make the conductor edges eqipotential.

Comment: A single charge about the $r=a$ will suffice, because the electric field must vanish for all $r>a$. The negative charge concentrates on the inner surface and causes an excess of positive charge at the _ends_ of the cylinder; for an infinite cylinder there is no charge on the outside surface and thus no electric field outside.

Comment: You are right, though, in that a single image charge will probably not be sufficient to solve for the field at $r<a$ and make the potential the same at all $z$. I suspect a line of (unequally distributed) charge, probably parallel to the cylinder, may be enough, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that no electric flux from the inside point charge $Q$ *leaks* from the conductor to outer space. Now we try to *build up* the system step by step:

First a charge density will be induced on the inner surface of the conductor. This induced surface charge on the inner surface distributes itself so that the total electric field will be zero **everywhere** (including inside the conductor itself).

Then, a charge will be induced on the outer surface of the conductor. This induced charge will distribute itself as if there wasn't any cavity in the conductor and we just had a *filled* piece of conductor with a total charge of $Q$.

So in your case, since the area of the conductor is infinite, the induced charge density on the outer side will be zero and no field will exist in outer space.